# Symfony doctrine entity manager injected in thread

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, pthreads

I'm trying to use doctrine entity manager in a thread. I use a static scope as suggested [here](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/369) . 
Class A is a symfony service and doctrine entity manager is injected in service.yml

```
class A extends \Thread{
static $em;
public function __construct($em)
    {
    self::$em = $em;
    }
    public function run(){
       self::$em->doSomething(); //here em is null
    }
}
```

How i can use entity manager correctly from a thread?

UPDATE:
As @Mjh suggested I can't share entity manager from threads. I can have an istance of em in every threads however but this is very inefficient.
A solution could be build a container threaded class shared between threads in which I'll store the entities that return from doctrine queries. The entities obviously will be detached from entity manager but I need only a read cache shared between threads.

UPDATE2:
See my first answer 
Open issue: avoid to initialize for every thread a new environment

Comment: `$em` probably can't be serialized, which means you should perform complete autoloading and creating the entity manager object (or any other dependent classes) in thread's `run` method. However, this brings up a question whether threading is correct for your approach and whether it even helps optimize anything.

Comment: Now we have N connectors that are launched by a php process. Every connector is a php process and is launched through an http request. Connectors  harvest data from web, do data manipulation ecc... I suppose that threads are better because we don't create a new php process every time.

Comment: Launching a process or spawning a thread on-request is never a good idea. Threads are lighter on the OS than processes are, but from what you said - you need a message queue, task distributor and worker pattern. You implemented those but using an inefficient approach. Ideally, you should "push" a task to the queue, then the workers take the task from the queue and deal with it. What you're doing is dynamically creating workers instead of having a set number of workers which deal with the task.

Comment: Thanx @Mjh for your opinion. We need assign maximum priority to parallelization in order to decrease final user waiting time. In fact every connector has to make web requests and data manipulation on responses. I think that a queue is not the good choice.

Comment: What we really need is a system to allow connectors to share data from doctrine entity manager to avoid to repeat queries on same data.

Comment: If the entity manager is a resource type of object (connections always are) then you can't share it between threads because they can't be serialized and that wouldn't be thread safe. It means you need an alternate solution. I did share a small part of what I *think* solves your problem, however I would strongly rethink whether the system you have in place really satisfies you entirely.. optimizing such systems takes careful planning, using some threads probably won't make it quicker. Be aware of adverse effect and good luck! :)

Comment: Tnx @Mjh . I will keep in mind your suggestions. If not we will have the best performance we hope at least that the system will be lighter.

Answer (score 1):

We have built a doctrine cache shared between thread extending a Thread Safe Stackable.
Warning some parts of code are semplified for demo purpose.

```
class work extends \Collectable{
   protected $parameters;
   public static $doctrine_mongodb;
   public function __construct($parameters){
      $this->parameters           = $parameters;
   }
   public function run()
   {
      try{
          $loader = require __DIR__.'/../../../../../../vendor/autoload.php';
          static::$container = unserialize($this->worker->container);
          static::$doctrine_mongodb     = static::$container->get('doctrine_mongodb');
        ...
        DO WORK
        $dm     = static::$doctrine_mongodb->getManager();
        $repo   = $dm->getRepository('Bundle:Document');
        $ris    = $this->worker->doctrinecache->FindOneBy($repo, array('key' => $val));
        ...
      }catch(\Exception $e){}
   }
}
```

NB: in work class we have the parallel execution of work code and there we can safely use doctrine common cache.
It's not the same to share entity manager because document are detached but for read purpose is good. If somebody need to manage entities can use merge doctrine method.

```
   class SWorker extends \Worker{
      public $env;
      public $debug; 
      public $mongodb_cache_engine;
      public function __construct( $env, $debug, $doctrinecache, $workParams){    
         $this->workParams            = $work;    
         $this->env                   = $env; 
         $this->debug                 = $debug;
         $this->doctrinecache         = $doctrinecache  ; 
      }

      public function start($options = null){
         return parent::start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE);
      }

      public function run(){
         require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../../../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
         require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../../../app/AppKernel.php';
         $kernel = new \AppKernel($this->env, $this->debug);
         $kernel->loadClassCache();
         $kernel->boot();
         $this->container = serialize($kernel->getContainer());   
      }
   }
```

In Sworker class we prepare symfony environment for thread. Tnx to svenpelster https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/369 for that.

```
class doctrinecache  extends \Stackable{
   public function __call($MethodName, $arguments){

      $repository = array_shift($arguments);
      $documentName = $repository->getDocumentName();    
      $hash = $this->generateHash($MethodName, $documentName, $arguments);
      return $this->cacheIO($hash, $repository, $MethodName, $arguments);
   }  
   public function cacheIO($hash, $repository, $MethodName, $arguments){
       $result = isset($this["{$hash}"])? $this["{$hash}"] : NULL;
       if(!$result){
          $result = call_user_func_array(array($repository, $MethodName), $arguments); 
          $this["{$hash}"] =  $result;
       }                    
       return $result;
    }
}
```

And finally

```
$doctrineCache = $this->kernel->get('doctrineCacheService');
$pool = new \Pool($workerNumber, SWorker::class, [$this->kernel->getEnvironment(), $this->kernel->isDebug(), $doctrineCache  ,$workParams]);    
while(current($works ))
{
     $pool->submit(current($works ));
     next($works);
}

$pool->shutdown();

while(current($works ))
{
     $arrayResults[] = current($works )->getResults();
     next($works);
}
```